# Ubuntu - executable file - variable assignment throwing error on script run

Tags: ubuntu, scripting

I am trying to run a small script - test - on ubuntu box.

It is as follows:

```
var1 = bash

var2 = /home/test/directory

...
...
<some more variable assignments and then program operations here>
...
...
```

Now every time I run it, then it throws errors:

```
root@localhost#/opt/test

/opt/test: line 1: var1: command not found
/opt/test: line 3: var2: command not found
...
...
more similar errors
...
```

Can someone help me understand what is wrong in this script?

Many thanks.

Comment: Your script really should start with something like `#!/bin/sh`, `#!/bin/bash`, or whatever shell you are using.

Comment: It does not use /bin/sh or /bin/bash. It assigns some variables and later uses python to execute scripts that refer to these variables. It was working fine 3 weeks or so earlier n then I updated the kernel. not sure what changed but this was working fine.

Comment: You cannot have a script without one of those.  If you haven't explicitly identified the shell using `#!` you are using then the shell you are currently running is being used.

Answer (score 3):

First, You need to escape the first string (the second string as a path DOES NOT require escaping)
   var1="Variable"
Second, There can't be any spaces in the syntax. 
   var2=/this/is/path/to/foo

Comment: Sorry, in my post, I meant, var1 = bash. Now, when I do: var1=bash var2=/opt/test, then I get this error: /opt/test: line 3: var2: command not found.

Comment: Are you separating the variables with newlines? Otherwise your script should read:

#!/bin/bash
var1="bash"
var2=/path/to/foo

Comment: Update: Now I made var2=/opt/test. So the error is gone. But on the next line, I have var3=$var2/another_file. Now it gives error saying: var3: command not found

Comment: Actually, this script was working fine earlier. Then I updated the kernel n now it has gone down. No idea what changed.

Comment: Are you able to post the script?

Comment: Also, you need to quote var3 the same as any other string.
ie: var3="$var2/bar"

Answer (score 0):

With out having the whole picture it's hard see what your trying to do, but it looks like your using a shell script to assign some environment variables before calling python.  You need to put "#!/bin/bash" (or what ever shell you want) at the top of your file as others mentioned. Running "/bin/bash scriptname" may also work, but no guarantees.

You may want to look at some of the shell programming tutorials out there (Google is your friend) to get pointing in the right direction.